# MFC maximizing view unexpectedly changes mainframe menu numbering

Tags: menu, mfc, docview

I have an MFC MDI Doc/View app. The main frame window has several menus, some standard, some I have created. I access these menus by using code such as

```
CMenu *pMenu = pM->GetMenu(); // get the main frame window's menu
CMenu *pMenuI = pMenu->GetSubMenu(iMenu);
```

`iMenu` is the left-to-right sequence of the menu on the main frame window's menu bar, e g, 0 is File, 1 is View, etc. This all works as expected.

My view is derived from `CScrollView`. If I load data, and click the maximize button in the system menu of the view, the view is maximized as expected, covering the entire client area of the main frame window.

But after maximizing, if I attempt to access the menus, I find that the numbering of the menus has changed. A new menu 0 has been added, and the menus I specified in the resource editor are numbered one higher, e g, now 1 is File, 2 is View, etc.

The new menu added is the system menu (&Restore, &Move, &Size, etc). The new menu does not appear on the main frame's menu bar.

What is the explanation for this behavior, and how can I avoid having my menus renumbered, or is there another way to identify them that doesn't depend on their left-to-right order?

Windows 11 VS2022 C++ 64-bit

Comment: There's something strange with your doc/view setup, it rather seems to be MDI actually. In a SDI app, the main (or single) view covers the entire client area of the main  window (or most of it, with some areas covered by other view types, employing custom code) and of course there are no Minimize/Maximize/Restore buttons for views, only for MDI child windows - in SDI apps the view is supposed to be permanently "maximized" (in respect to the main frame window). You can use the `IsKindOf()` function or the debugger to check the actual type of your runtime objects.

Comment: @Constantine Georgiou: You're right--it's an MDI app. But it only allows a single doc at a time to be loaded, hence my confusion. I changed SDI to MDI in the original posting.

Comment: You can use the `isZoomed()` member of the frame window class; if that returns non-zero, just add 1 to your `iMenu`.

Comment: If you show a bit more code, which demonstrates how you are getting that `iMenu` value, then someone may post an answer. At the moment, this question lack a [MRE].

Comment: I found an `isZoomed` function defined in winuser.h. Note that it is the view (CScrollView) window that is maximized, not the frame window. I feel uneasy using this method, because I don't know why it should work, and without documentation, I can't say whether a restore-maximize cycle would change the menu numbering.

Comment: In answer to how am I getting `iMenu`, it is the left-to-right order of the menus on the menu bar, defined by the resource editor; when I want to change a menu item, I give that number to my code. I believe an example could be obtained by creating an MFC doc/view project using MDI, and a standard menu bar. But it is not an example I am looking for, it's knowledge of how to use menus properly in an MDI project.

Comment: As you have noticed, when the active MDI child window is maximized, there is an extra menu on the main frame's menu bar. Checking the 'isZoomed()` return value on the active window will be what you need to do.

Comment: There are other ways to do what you want. You can search your menus by name rather than use a (fixed) index. But, as already said, we need more details/code *in the question itself, not in comments.*

Comment: If you look into the resources you will find two menus, one with an ID of `IDR_MAINFRAME` and (at least) one more, with an ID like `IDR_MYDOCTYPE` (one per doc-type or doc-template, can't remember exactly). The former is displayed when there is no document open, the latter when a document of the corresponding type becomes the active one. This is done by the MFC framework. The two menus do have some common/duplicate items, with the `IDR_MAINFRAME` one typically lacking the Edit submenu. Still, you should better populate your menus using their command IDs rather their position.